# pythonic way: Iterator chaining and resource management

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I find it difficult to articulate smoothly chained iterators and resource management in Python.

It will probably be clearer by examining a concrete example:

I have this little program that works on a bunch of similar, yet different csv files. As they are shared with other co-workers, I need to open and close them frequently. Moreover, I need to transform and filter their content. So I have a lot of different fonctions of this kind:

```
def doSomething(fpath):
    with open(fpath) as fh:
        r=csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';')
        s=imap(lambda row: fn(row), r)
        t=ifilter(lambda row: test(row), s)
        for row in t:
            doTheThing(row)
```

That's nice and readable, but, as I said, I have a lot of those and I end up copy-pasting a lot more than I'd wish. But of course I can't refactor the common code into a function returning an iterator:

```
def iteratorOver(fpath):
    with open(fpath) as fh:
        r=csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';')
        return r #oops! fh is closed by the time I use it
```

A first step to refactor the code would be to create another 'with-enabled' class:

```
def openCsv(fpath):
    class CsvManager(object):
        def __init__(self, fpath):
            self.fh=open(fpath)
        def __enter__(self):
            return csv.reader(self.fh, delimiter=';')
        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            self.fh.close()
```

and then:

```
with openCsv('a_path') as r:
    s=imap(lambda row: fn(row), r)
    t=ifilter(lambda row: test(row), s)
    for row in t:
        doTheThing(row)
```

But I only reduced the boilerplate of each function by one step.

So what is the pythonic way to refactor such a code? My c++ background is getting in the way I think.

Comment: Pity you can't use Python 3... But anyway, you can improve those `imap` & `ifilter` calls. Get rid of those lambdas! Instead, do `imap(fn, r)` and `ifilter(test, s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *generators*; these produce an iterable you can then pass to other objects. For example, a generator yielding all the rows in a CSV file:

```
def iteratorOver(fpath):
    with open(fpath) as fh:
        r = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';')
        for row in r:
            yield row
```

Because a generator function *pauses* whenever you are not iterating over it, the function doesn't exit until the loop is complete and the `with` statement won't close the file.

You can now use that generator in a filter:

```
rows = iteratorOver('some path')
filtered = ifilter(test, rows)
```

etc.

Comment: Another option, maybe not worth a whole other answer, is to just use a higher-ordered function -- take `fn`, `test`, and `doTheThing` as arguments to `doSomething`.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield: but that's not nearly as flexible. What if you wanted to apply a chain of filters and maps?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you stop looping over the generator before you exhaust it (maybe you put it in an `any` that short-circuited), you end up relying on the generator's `__del__` to close the file. That usually happens immediately on CPython, but it can cause subtle compatibility issues with other Python implementations. Theoretically, you could do `with contextlib.closing(whatever_generator)`, but it's kind of awkward and I've never seen anyone do that.

Comment: @user2357112: that's not the loop ending. That's the generator not being consumed until the end. Yes, `contextlib.closing()` could help there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I meant the loop over the generator, not the loop within the generator.